# What is the best way to read the code of already defined function (especially from the System` context)?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, reverse-engineering

Occasionally we like to look into how certain `` System` `` functions are defined (when they're written in Mathematica).  This question is about the best way to do that.

Points to keep in mind:

- Of couse `ReadProtected` needs to be removed first.
- Builtins usually need to be used at least once before they get loaded into the kernel.  Is a single simple invocation usually sufficient for this when they have extended functionality (e.g. through options)?
- `Information` (`??`) gives the definition in a hard-to-read format (no indentation, and all private context names prepended).  What is the best way to get rid of the context names, and get formatted code?

  <sup>One idea for getting rid of certain contexts is `` Block[{$ContextPath = Append[$ContextPath, "SomeContext`Private`"], Information[symbol]] ``.  Code can be auto-formatted using Workbench.  Some issues remain, e.g. `Information` doesn't quote strings, preventing the code from being able to be copied into Workbench.</sup>

Generally, I'm interested in how people do this, what methods they use to make the code of builtins as easy to read as possible.

Use case: For example, recently I digged into the code of `RunThrough` when I found out that it simply doesn't work on Windows XP (turns out it fails to quote the names of temp files when the path to them contains spaces).

---

**Update:**  [It appears](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Feb/msg00515.html) that there used to be a function for printing definitions without context prepended, `` Developer`ContextFreeForm ``, but it's not working any more in newer versions.

Comment: You can get rid of the private context names by entering the context before calling `?? <symbolname>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Regarding the pretty-printing: the following is a very schematic code which builds on the answer of @Mr.Wizard to show that a few simple rules can go a long way towards improving the readability of the code:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{RunThrough},
   Unprotect[RunThrough];
   ClearAttributes[RunThrough, ReadProtected];
   Block[{$ContextPath = Append[$ContextPath, "System`Dump`"]},
      With[{boxes = ToBoxes@ DownValues[RunThrough]},
         CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[#], "Input"]] &[
            boxes /. 
            f_[left___, "\[RuleDelayed]", right___] :> 
                 f[left, "\[RuleDelayed]", "\n", right] //.
           {
             RowBox[{left___, ";", next : Except["\n"], right___}] :> 
                 RowBox[{left, ";", "\n", "\t", next, right}],
             RowBox[{sc : ("Block" | "Module" | "With"), "[", 
               RowBox[{vars_, ",", body_}], "]"}] :>
                 RowBox[{sc, "[", RowBox[{vars, ",", "\n\t", body}], "]"}]
           }]]]]
```

This is for sure not a general solution (in particular it won't work well on deeply nested functional code without many separate statements), but I am sure it can be improved and generalized without too much trouble to cover many cases of interest.

Comment: This works very well for practical purposes on this limited example!  @Mr.Wizard I found an [interesting visualization of M- program code](http://taliesinb.net/quicksort-in-61-characters), unfortunately he doesn't give the code to produce it.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Interesting.  Did you try contacting the author?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, no reply so far.  But it's the holiday season.

Comment: @Szabolcs I couldn't help noticing that the quicksort function on that page is not well optimized.  I would write:  `quicksort = # & @@@ {# //. x : {y_, __} :> (## & @@ Reverse /@ GatherBy[x, # < y &])} &` which is both shorter and faster.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Write a comment there.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I didn't see the comments (script blocking) before.  This is already covered there.

Answer (score 5):

Good question, because I don't think I have seen this discussed yet.

I do essentially the same thing you outlined.  You can get a somewhat different print-out with `Definition`, and more information with `FullDefinition`:

```
Unprotect[RunThrough];

ClearAttributes[RunThrough, ReadProtected]

Block[{$ContextPath = Append[$ContextPath, "System`Dump`"]}, 
  Print @ FullDefinition @ RunThrough
]
```

Comment: +1 I didn't realize you could manipulate context path to achieve the same objective (of getting rid of the prepended private context names). I always used BeginContext. I think the remainder of the OPs question evaluates to "how do you pretty-print Mathematica code?" The only source code formatter I'm aware of is in the editor context menu of Wolfram Workbench.

Comment: @cah There's one more important issue.  Try copying the `RunThrough` code to Workbench and you'll see it gives syntax errors.  It's because quotes around strings are not printed, and this one even contains a couple on whitespace-only strings.  So the next thing is: how to get the source on a pasteable form?  The `$ContextPath` method I did mention in my question too in small type.

Comment: @cah What `Begin` and friends do is simply modifying `$ContextPath`, nothing more.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm not sure if you knew that it's not necessary to `Unprotect` to be able to remove `ReadProtected`.  I think `Protected` doesn't affect changing attributes.

Comment: @Szabolcs No, I did not realize that.  I don't see the problem with copy&paste, but I also don't have Workbench.  If I copy to a new cell it appears correct.

Comment: Let me clarify: if you look at how `WriteString[tmpfile, "\n"]` is formatted, you'll see that `"\n"` appears as an actual newline (it's not visible at all that it's a string).  If I copy and paste the code to a text editor (try notepad), then it will paste the same way (a newline will be pasted instead of `"\n"`).  The sole reason I'd like to paste to Workbench is because it has an "format code" command, but it works only if the expression is syntactically correct.